# In Scala, why do I need to import something only if I use it as a return type?

Tags: scala

I use Scala in order to write short Spark scripts, and I noticed something strange. If I want to create a DataFrame and perform operations on it, I don't need to import anything. For instance,

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json("somePath")
df.show(false)
```

runs just fine. But if I want to write a method that returns a dataframe, I need to explicitly import the DataFrame class first

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def foo(path:String) :  DataFrame = {
    val df = ...
    return df
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All that an import statement does is to bring a name into scope so you can refer to it by its unqualified name. That is, importing `DataFrame` allows you to write just `DataFrame` instead of having to write its full name `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`.

So if you're okay with writing the full name or you're not writing the name at all, you don't need the import. In your first code the latter is the case.

PS: You don't need a return statement at the end of your method. The last expression in a method is returned automatically.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you! I was aware that I don't need a return statement, but as a java programmer, I feel wrong not including it :)

Comment: Or let the compiler infer the type, omit DataFrame. Also, in spark shell you get some imports for free, you can add more. https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/repl/scala-2.11/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/repl/SparkILoop.scala#L39L68

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo(path:String) : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame  = {
    val df = ...
    return df
}
```

will work without import. You need to import only if you want to use short names.